# sqlserver get records count repeating

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have one doubt in sql server
get records based on installments
Table :productdetails

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[productdetails](
    [productid] [int] NULL,
    [Productrstartdate] [date] NULL,
    [Productenddate] [date] NULL,
    [EMIInstallment] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[productdetails] ([productid], [Productrstartdate], [Productenddate], [EMIInstallment]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2020-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2024-10-02' AS Date), 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[productdetails] ([productid], [Productrstartdate], [Productenddate], [EMIInstallment]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2020-02-10' AS Date), CAST(N'2021-02-10' AS Date), 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[productdetails] ([productid], [Productrstartdate], [Productenddate], [EMIInstallment]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2019-01-10' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-01-10' AS Date), 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[productdetails] ([productid], [Productrstartdate], [Productenddate], [EMIInstallment]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2019-01-18' AS Date), CAST(N'2021-01-18' AS Date), 3)
GO
```

based on above data i want output like below

```
Productid |Installmentdate  |noofinstallmentcount
1         |2020-10-02       |1
1         |2021-10-02       |2
1         |2022-10-02       |3
1         |2023-10-02       |4
1         |2024-10-02       |5
2         |2020-02-10       |1
2         |2021-02-10       |2
3         |2019-01-10       |1
4         |2019-01-18       |1
4         |2020-01-18       |2
4         |2021-01-18       |3
```

i tried like below :

```
DECLARE @MINDATE DATE='2019-01-18'
DECLARE @COUNT INT=10
dECLARE @MAXDATE DATE='2024-10-02'

;WITH ABC
AS 
(
SELECT  productid ,@MINDATE CalendarDate ,1 as id from [dbo].[productdetails]
UNION ALL
SELECT a.productid ,DATEADD(YEAR,1,a.Productrstartdate ), 1 FROM  [dbo].[productdetails] a
join  [dbo].[productdetails]  b on a.productid=b.productid
 WHERE   @MINDATE <@MAXDATE     ) 
 SELECT * FROM ABC
```

above query not given expected output

could you please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server .

Answer (score 0):

You want a tally here. If you're not going to have a value (much) higher than `10`, then just a `VALUES` clause will work:

```
SELECT pd.productid,
       DATEADD(YEAR, V.I, pd.Productrstartdate) AS Installmentdate,
       V.I + 1 AS noofinstallmentcount
FROM dbo.productdetails pd
     JOIN (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9))V(I) ON pd.EMIInstallment > V.I;
```

If you need bigger numbers, just use a bigger tally:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1000 rows
SELECT pd.productid,
       DATEADD(YEAR, T.I, pd.Productrstartdate) AS Installmentdate,
       T.I + 1 AS noofinstallmentcount
FROM dbo.productdetails pd
     JOIN Tally T ON pd.EMIInstallment > T.I;
```

Comment: can we do without values(0 to 9),we have more than 50instalments.itsnot work.can you please help on it

Comment: The examples only had up to `5`, @gbalu, so I just assumed you had lower numbers, you can easily make bigger tallies.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp table that mimics the actual `productdetails` table, then iterate through it, creating an output table that lists the product id with each installment date. Once you have that, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to count the installment numbers. Try this:

```
SELECT *
INTO #productdetails
FROM productdetails

CREATE TABLE #output (
    productid int null
    ,installmentdate date null)

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #productdetails) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @yr int = 0
    WHILE (SELECT TOP 1 DATEDIFF(year, DATEADD(year, @yr, Productrstartdate), productenddate) FROM #productdetails) >= 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #output (
            productid
            ,installmentdate)
        SELECT top 1
            productid
            ,DATEADD(year, @yr, Productrstartdate) installmentdate
        FROM #productdetails

        SET @yr = @yr + 1
    END

    DELETE TOP (1) FROM #productdetails
END

SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY InstallmentDate asc) NumberOfInstallmentCount
FROM #output

DROP TABLE #output, #productdetails
```